# Failed SSH into instance

Tags: openstack

I have 15 instances running with same security group, however I can SSH into some of them but not the others. I received "Permission denied (publickey)" message for those instances. I also confirm that all instances are using the same public key and I try to ssh into all of them with the same private key.

What do I miss?

Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting "Permission denied (publickey)", it is not a security group issue.  It is most likely one of the following:

1. You didn't specify the public key to use when launching some of the instances.
2. There was a problem with the metadata service on some of the instances which meant that cloud-init was unable to retrieve the public key.
3. You are using the wrong credentials; e.g. the admin account name is different on the different instances.  (The default is OS dependent.)
4. You have multiple keys in your ~/.ssh directory and they are being tried in the wrong order.  If you have `fail2ban` set up on the server side, each time that the client supplies a key counts as a login attempt.  You can hit the limit before you tried the key that is going to work.

If you look at the respective instance's console log from their first boot, you can see which public keys were actually used.  This can be used to diagnose 1 and 2.

For 3, check the OS documentation.

For 4, try using the `ssh` command's `-i` option to specify the path to the private key file.

There are other possibilities; e.g. if you launched instances from a non-pristine image / snaphot.

Reference:

- [Troubleshooting SSH access to a NeCTAR instance](https://support.ehelp.edu.au/support/solutions/articles/6000149723)

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for your reply. I have checked and make sure that 1,3,4 are correctly configured. However I do get "No active metadata service found" error when cloud-init trying to run util.py. After more tests I realised that the instance works some times but failed most of the time. According to this https://support.ehelp.edu.au/support/solutions/articles/6000149723 there seems to no have a good solution. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Well ... that support article is about troubleshooting from the perspective of a user of a VM rather than from the perspective of someone who manages the OpenStack cloud infrastructure.

Comment: Try Googling for "openstack metadata service not responding".  There are some promising results.

Comment: I couldn't find anything useful for my case. Eventually I found out that creating instance with user other than admin most of the time always run into  "No active metadata service found" error. But if I create instances with admin, everything works as normal. For now this is good enough. Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK ... so there is something weird about your setup.  The account used to create instances shouldn't be relevant. But I don't have any expertise on debugging the metadata service.  Except to suggest that you trawl the logs for all related services for any clues.

Comment: Are all VMs that fail on the same hypervisor?